# how to use the redis as Semantic cache with help of vectorfield

Tags: python, caching, redis, openai-api

I am creating a chatbot with Openai and I need to cache the response from Openai. InMemory Cache is done from my side and all is working well. I need to upgrade the cache mechanism to Semantic caching so I can reduce the cost-effectively.

New Redis has the option to save the data to a vector field and I am on confusion how to store the data in the vector field. if any of you can help will be very thankful